Warning:: Passing the class as positional argument is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.2
 serialize :reddoorz_property_ids, type: Object



DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the class as positional argument is
deprecated and will be removed in Rails 7.2. Please pass the class as
a keyword argument:

What is the solution to eliminating this warning?
I am migrating my project to rails 7.1

Are you using ActiveStorage?

Are you certain that is where the error is being raised? That message will only be raised when you are passing a second positional argument, not when using keyword arguments, serialize :reddoorz_property_ids, Object or serialize :reddoorz_property_ids, JSON, type: Object e.g.  Source

Do you actually need/want to use serialize? Use a join table instead or if you really have to an array type column.

@dbugger No we aren't using active storage in our project

I guess your using the globalize gem? In this case: It seems that the serialize method of globalize is setting the class_name_or_coder attribute to Object which let's ActiveRecord then print the deprecation warning.
This is an already known problem, see Github Issue. As I understand globalize has provided a fix for the problem with this: serialization
EDIT:
For me gem "globalize", "~> 7.0" inside my Gemfile did the trick since now the attribute class_name_or_coder is set to nil by default which prevents the generation of the deprecation warning. (Like mentioned: serialization)

Yes we are using globalize gem , but this is not occurring only in models using globalize .

It doesn't matter if some of your models use the globalize gem or not. If you have it defined in your Gemfile Globalize will modify ActiveRecord at core level means even if you're not using globalize inside some of your models they still inherit the behavior from ActiveRecord modified by Globalize.
You will notice when prying into the serialize method in one of your models, you will be redirected to the globalize-6.3.0/lib/patches/active_record/rails6_1/serialization.rb:5
